# Problemas para iniciar simulador ios con flutter

Tags: flutter, ios

Hola tengo el siguiente error al tratar de hacer el debug en un simulador de ios con flutter. Utilicé el comando `flutter doctor`y también `flutter doctor -v`pero me dice que no existe ningún error. También intenté haciendo un `flutter clean` y luego `flutter run`pero el error persiste. Ha alguien más le pasó? De antemano muchas gracias!
[image: Holaaa]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a correr tu aplicación directamente usando el xcode y mira si es capas de levantarla al parecer es un problema mas relacionado con xcode que con flutter saludos

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/318833)